# Add connection dialog closing when fetching list of SQL servers

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I have jus installed VS 2008 on a new machine and when I open up the Add connection dialog box to conect to the SQLExpress server on my machine the diolog box just closes.

It's fine until you try and populate the list of running servers then just closes, with no error message :(

Has anyone else come across this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Microsoft AutoComplete wasn't registered in the registry, and was causing the dialog box to crash when you try and type.

Runing the following .reg file seems to fix it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062}]
@="Microsoft AutoComplete"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,62,00,72,00,\
  6f,00,77,00,73,00,65,00,75,00,69,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062}]
@="Microsoft AutoComplete"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,62,00,72,00,\
6f,00,77,00,73,00,65,00,75,00,69,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
```